# Asana API - Create Webhook

Tags: apex, rest-api, webhooks

I'm trying to create asana webhook through apex.

I keep failing the authentication phase - handshake:

> {"errors":[{"message":"Could not complete activation handshake with
>   target URL. Please ensure that the receiving server is accepting
>   connections and supports SSL","help":"For more information on API
>   status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors:
>   https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}

I'm missing some thing and not sure what.

I tried to create a class with @RestResource notation for handshake post callback:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/AsanaWeb/*')
global class asanaCallbackCtrl {

public asanaCallbackCtrl(system.RestRequest req) {

}

@HttpPost
global static void doPost() {
    asanaCallbackCtrl ctrl = new asanaCallbackCtrl(RestContext.request); //asanaCallbackCtrl.newInstance(RestContext.request);
    RestResponse resp  = ctrl.executePost();
    RestContext.response.statusCode   = resp.statusCode;
    RestContext.response.responseBody = resp.responseBody;
   // the record not inserted to database..
   Log__c log = new Log__c();
    log.Body__c = JSON.serialize(resp.responseBody);
    log.Response_Hedears__c =  JSON.serialize(resp.headers);
    log.Staus_Code__c = string.valueOf(resp.statusCode);
    insert log;
}

public RestResponse executePost() {
    RestResponse  resp    = new RestResponse();
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;


    try {
        Blob targetBlob = Blob.valueOf(res.headers.get('X-Hook-Secret'));
        // Generate SHA1 digest
        Blob hashSHA1 = Crypto.generateDigest('hmacSHA1', targetBlob);
        // For Rackspace Compatiblity encode the binary into BASE 64
        // this will result in 28 chars long string
        String hashBase64SHA1 = EncodingUtil.base64encode (hashSHA1);

        resp.addHeader('X-Hook-Secret', res.headers.get('X-Hook-Secret'));
        // verify the incoming request as legit; throw exception otherwise

        resp.statusCode = 200;
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        resp.statusCode = 500;// set per doc (403 or 500)

    }

    // persist some log so you have a record of the incoming request
    return resp;
}

/**
 * Create a new task using Asana API
 */
public static HttpResponse createWebhook() {
    object resource = '486792005021811';

    string target = 'https://bringgsb-bringg.cs17.force.com/AsanaWeb/services/apexrest/AsanaWeb/486792005021811';
    NewWebhook newHook = new NewWebhook(resource, target);


    //NewTask newTask = new NewTask(new string[]{'139836167870950'}, '6125975198930', 'Lee Test Api', 'Test Notes');
    String JSONString = JSON.serialize(newHook);
    JSONString = '{"data":' + JSONString + '}';
    HttpResponse res;
    string base64Key = createAuthorizationHeader('0/859eb48d9719099d88cb2cfab4dbcb2e');
    /**
     * API call cannot be made while test class in running.
     * so setting the expected response on which code would run
     */
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {

    } else {
        res = sendHttp(asanaEndPoint + '/webhooks', 'POST', JSONString  , 'Basic ' + base64Key);
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

I added this class to my site (Enable apex classes), but not sure if I put the correct url for my target: (i'm running in sandbox)

```
https://**[siteURL?]**/services/apexrest/**[domainName?]**/AsanaWeb/486792005021811
```

Comment: what is the status code? did you checl https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors, looks more like something you should check on the Asana Community

Comment: Hi,
I'm getting status code 400: No authorization, A valid API key was not provided with the request, so the API could not associate a user with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up and debugging webhooks can be tricky

My example below is for Shopify but it may help you in your setup

Site (sandbox) definition:

```
http://sandboxName-myCompanyName.mysandboxPod.force.com/shopify
```

or, specifically

```
http://dev-foocompany.cs79.force.com/shopify
```

The URL that you place into the webhook originator:

```
https://dev-foocompany.cs79.force.com/shopify/services/apexrest/shopify/neworder
```

The essence of the REST class is:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/shopify/*')
    global class ShopifyWebhookResponder
@HttpPost
    global static void doPost() {
      RestResponse resp  = ShopifyWebHookResponder.newInstance(RestContext.request).executePost();
      RestContext.response.statusCode   = resp.statusCode;
      RestContext.response.responseBody = resp.responseBody;
    }

    public RestResponse executePost() {
      RestResponse  resp    = new RestResponse();

      try {
        // verify the incoming request as legit; throw exception otherwise
        resp.responseBody = ... // process the body and build response 
        resp.statusCode = 200;
      }

      catch (Exception e) {
        resp.statusCode = // set per doc (403 or 500)
      }

      // persist some log so you have a record of the incoming request
      return resp;
}
```

The two keys are:

- Return the correct HTTP statusCode per the doc of the webhook originator
- Persist to a custom object `Log__c` (or use Platform Events) everything that happens to your webhook responder as you won't be able to use debug statements as there is no running user to trace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply..
I tried modify my code by your suggestion, but I still not reaching to "doPost"..

can you explain:  RestResponse resp  = ShopifyWebHookResponder.newInstance(RestContext.request).executePost();

any suggestion?

Thnks, Lee